# How to access Node.js package in React JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, serverless

I am working on **React Serverless App using AWS** I want to access Node JS specific package into React js what are possible alternatives to access node js package without using Node JS on the backend

**font-list** is a Node.js package for listing the fonts available on your system.
I want to access this package on the frontend side.

Need Help!!

Comment: What package you want to use? 
If that package make file system request, it will not possible because React is in browser

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina the author said it's `font-list`. And I belive they're aware that it does not work in browser.

Comment: For this specific task, you would have to implement font detection, which is not trivial. See how https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2 does it.

Comment: after installing font in the system, **Figma** UI designing tool on the Web developed on the React detects it, and render it on the web.

Using XHR on network tab
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:44950/figma/font-file?file=%2FUsers%2FUSER-NAME%2FLibrary%2FFonts%2FApercu%20Italic.otf   

how they are doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the broader question, a package meant for node will more than likely work only in the node eco system.

In the case of `font-list`, it looks like it's running a vbs script to get available fonts (in the case of windows). Running external scripts like that, or accessing local file systems is not something you can do in a browser environment due do security constraints.

So to get a list of fonts in a browser will require a its own solution. You cannot just use a Node.js package, even though it's all still js.

Comment: I am working on a Font Manager app using React JS on frontend and Serverless Lambda on the backend I want to access system fonts using react what are possible ways to access system fonts into React JS app. do I have to use NodeJS with React and Lambda or any possible alternative to access system file/directories?

or how to access System fonts directory using javascript.
Need Help

Comment: @AliSyed You will not be able to access system fonts using the browser. It simply doesn't have access. The closest thing you can do is detect what fonts the browser has available. There are ways of doing that as someone commented on your answer.